# Dynamically change spell checking on a key stroke

Tags: vim, spell-checking

Hello I discovered about `spelllang` if vim. I am trying to achieve to following:

1. When I press say F7 a dialogue is opened asking me if I want to activate the french or english dictionary `set spelllang=fr spell` or `set spelllang=en spell`
2. When I press F7 again `spell` is disabled

Can I do something like this easily in my `vimrc` ?

Cheers (I am using gvim and windows but I guess it won't matter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this. I wrote a little script for illustration. You can put it as is into your `.vimrc`.

The key point is the use of `inputlist()` which prompts the user to enter a number. Of course you can expand `spelllang_list` that contains the list of possible languages by any desire.

```
function! <SID>ToggleSpell()
    let spelllang_list = [ 'fr', 'en' ]
    let string = []

    for i in range(len(spelllang_list))
        call add(string, i+1 . ") " . spelllang_list[i])
    endfor

    if ! &spell
        let &spell = 1
        let selection = inputlist(string)
        let &spelllang = spelllang_list[selection-1]
    else
        let &spell = 0
        echo "'spell' disabled..."
    endif
endfunction

noremap <F7> :call <SID>ToggleSpell()<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about adding

```
nnoremap <F7>:set spelllang=en<CR>
nnoremap <F8>:set spelllang=fr<CR>
nnoremap <F9>:set spell!
```

This will make F9 toggling the spell state (in normal mode). If you want all the actions to toggle between states you should write a vimscript function which saves state information and acts on that.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a little more advance stuff (I am hoping to use a single map for all this)

Answer (score 1):

I have the following, which uses only one key:

```
setlocal nospell
let g:togglespell = 0
let g:default_langn = 1 "1 for English, 2 for Portuguese
function! ToggleSpell()
  if v:count != 0
    let g:default_langn = v:count
    let g:togglespell = 0 " force spelling this time
  endif
  if g:togglespell == 0
    if g:default_langn == 1
      setlocal spell spelllang=en_us
      echo "language = en_us"
    elseif g:default_langn == 2
      setlocal spell spelllang=pt
      echo "language = pt"
    else
      echom "No language corresponding to such option [1: English, 2 Portuguese]"
    endif
    let g:togglespell = 1
  else
    setlocal nospell
    let g:togglespell = 0
    echo "No spell Checking"
  endif
endfunction
noremap <F8> :<C-U>call ToggleSpell()<CR>
```

with this you press `<F8>` and by default it toggles between no spelling and spelling in English.
If you invoke it with a count, say `2<F8>` then from that point on it will toggle between spelling in Portuguese or no spelling.